# Config Wizard error in Rspamd on dkim step in Debian Bullseye

Tags: configuration, dkim, debian-bullseye, rspamd

Using fresh **Debian 11.7** installation I’m trying to setup `RSpamd` using `configwizard`, but in the last step of building the private key I got the following error:

```
Do you want to create privkey /var/lib/rspamd/dkim/domain.tld.2023.key[Y/n]: y
call to rspamadm lua script failed (2): /usr/share/rspamd/lualib/rspamadm//configwizard.lua:382: attempt to call field 'generate_keypair' (a nil value); trace: [1]:{/usr/share/rspamd/lualib/rspamadm//configwizard.lua:784 - <unknown> [Lua]};
```

RSpamd was installed using guide from https://rspamd.com/downloads.html for Debian distro. Same steps for RSpamd from official Debian repo is fine, but the version of RSpamd in official Debian repo is too old. Any suggestions?